# preg_match()で、狙った文字列に含まれる文字列を余計に取ってしまう

Tags: php, 正規表現

コード

```
<?php
$test = 'this is October 02, 2017 today';
$months = "/(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|
　　　September|October|November|December) [0-3][0-9], 20[0-9]+/";

preg_match($months, $test, $date);

var_dump($date);
?>
```

`October 02, 2017`が取りたい。
出力結果

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "October 02, 2017" [1]=> string(7) "October" }
```

狙った文字列は取れているものの、余計に`October`単体でも取れてしまっている。
何が原因でこのようになっているのか教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

[サブパターン](http://php.net/manual/ja/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php)には種類があり単純な`()`ではキャプチャが行われます。今回`October`が返されたのもキャプチャが行われた結果です。キャプチャを行いたくないサブパターンでは`(?:)`を使用します。

```
$months = "/(?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) [0-3][0-9], 20[0-9]+/";
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
期待結果を取得することができました。
仰る通り`()`によるキャプチャが原因でした。

Comment: @yotsua 問題点はまだ解決されていないのでしょうか？ 質問を継続されるのでしたら、解決できていない点を明確にしてください。